# Should I extract private method to unit test class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have the following class where all the logic that I want to unit test happens within a private method I extracted for reuse for the two Handle methods to invoke. What I am stuck on is the proper way to unit test this class. There are essentially 4 observable behaviors I want to assert:

1. Does not call 'Replace' when a registration does not exist
2. Does not call 'Replace' when a document does not exist
3. Does not call 'Replace' when the document message is current
4. Calls 'Replace' when all other conditions succeed

I could easily duplicate all the unit tests for the two public Handle methods. But I was wondering if it would be more appropriate to extract the private method out to a class that exposes this behavior using a public method I can directly test against.

Thoughts?

```
public class Denormalizer :
    INotificationHandler<LightsMessageReceived>,
    INotificationHandler<AnnouncementsMessageReceived>
{
    public Task Handle(AnnouncementsMessageReceived notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return HandleMessage(notification, document => document.Announcements, cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task Handle(LightsMessageReceived notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return HandleMessage(notification, document => document.Lights, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task HandleMessage(InventoryMessage message, Func<SaleRegistration, ISequenced> getMessageId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var registration = await docContext.CsoMessage.GetSaleRegistration(message.SiteId, message.InventoryId, cancellationToken);

        if (registration == null) return;

        var document = await docContext.SaleRegistration.Get(message.SiteId, message.InventoryId, 
            registration.Data.SaleDate, registration.Data.SaleType, cancellationToken);

        if (document == null) return;

        if (getMessageId(document).IsCurrent(message.MessageId)) return;

        document.Map(message);

        await docContext.SaleRegistration.Replace(document);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create the helper class you just mentioned.

It's usually smart to create such classes and test them, as long as the logic remains the same.

Comment: Yes? No? Maybe? Honestly, how should anyone give an objective answer here? This is completely opinion-based. The only thing you should care about is the Single-Responsibility-Principle. We can´t determine if this is okay here.

Comment: Why do you care *how* public methods are performing their actions provided that they *are* honouring their public contracts?

Comment: Are there any reason you cannot test the private method through the public methods? It looks like you just need to verify the different calls on the dependencies. If the dependcies are not injected, the class should be refactored for testability

Comment: this is a perfectly valid question and shouldn't have been closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is to move the code to another class that you can test. However, neither the class nor the method need to be `public`. You can also mark them with the `internal` access modifier so that you can only access the code from the same assembly.

In addition also assemblies that you explicitly grant access to the internal members can also access the method. You can use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute on your main assembly and grant access to the unit test assembly. This way, you do not publish the method completely while allowing the unit test to access it.

Of course, this also works if you decide to leave the method in the class and just mark it `internal`, so you don't have to create a class of its own (though this might be cleaner).

Comment: thank you for your feedback

Comment: @Marco you're welcome